# Get two or more consecutive capitalized words from html text using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to extract all sequences of two or more words where the first letter of each is capitalized. I thought this `'[A-Z][a-z]+(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+'` would work but it is adding characters which I can't explain.

Here's the full code:

```
import re
import unittest
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_page = """
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr class=tb1><td>Lorem Ipsum dolor Sit amet</td></tr>
<tr class=tb1><td>Consectetuer adipiscing elit</td></tr>
<tr><td>Aliquam Tincidunt mauris eu Risus</td></tr>
<tr><td>Vestibulum Auctor Dapibus neque</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
text = soup.get_text()

def get_sequences(page):
    ex = re.compile('[A-Z][a-z]+(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+')
    sequences = re.findall(ex, page)
    return sequences

print get_sequences(text)
```

The desired result should be
`['Lorem Ipsum', 'Aliquam Tincidunt', 'Vestibulum Auctor Dapibus']`

But instead I'm getting
`[u'Lorem Ipsum', u'Aliquam Tincidunt', u' Risus\nVestibulum Auctor Dapibus']`

Comment: It is not adding characters, it returns expected strings.

Comment: Ah thank you! That makes sense.

Comment: You are getting unicode format text. So, you need to encode them.

Answer (score 1):

The approach is correct but not directed. What you are looking for is two or more consecutive capitalized words *in a line*. So, you should run the regex on lines in the text. This does the trick:

```
def get_sequences(page):
    ex = re.compile('[A-Z][a-z]+(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+')
    sequences = []
    for x in page.splitlines():
        sequences.append(re.findall(ex, x))
    sequences = sum(sequences,[])
    return sequences
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
((?:[A-Z][a-z]+\s*){2,})
```

https://regex101.com/r/EeS7F5/1 for examples

You can also modify your current regex and get rid of the lookahead

view https://regex101.com/r/vViHXm/1

Comment: Hmm this actually didn't work. It ended up adding a bunch `\n` inside each list item.

Answer (score 0):

**Python Code:**

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"[A-Z][a-z]+\s+[A-Z][a-z]+"

test_str = ("<html>\n"
    "<body>\n"
    "<table>\n"
    "<tr class=tb1><td>Lorem Ipsum dolor Sit amet</td></tr>\n"
    "<tr class=tb1><td>Consectetuer adipiscing elit</td></tr>\n"
    "<tr><td>Aliquam Tincidunt mauris eu Risus</td></tr>\n"
    "<tr><td>Vestibulum Auctor Dapibus neque</td></tr>\n"
    "</table>\n"
    "</body>\n"
    "</html>\n"
    "\"\"\"")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches):
    matchNum = matchNum + 1

    print (match.group())

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

**RESULT:**

```
Lorem Ipsum
Aliquam Tincidunt
Vestibulum Auctor
```

**See:** http://ideone.com/iQev8D